# How to enter Devanagari half-R character in Emacs MULE?

Tags: emacs, unicode

I am trying the Emacs [MULE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MULE) [ITRANS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITRANS) input method to enter Devanagari unicode text. I am looking to enter a key sequence for Devanagari letter `"Half-R"` (`ऱ्`) i.e. `U0931 U094d` (which should be mapped to `R` according to the [ITRANS Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITRANS)). While all other keys in the map work fine, this particular one does not!

I know I can use `M-x ucs-insert` (or `CTRL-x-8 RET`) to enter this sequence, but it is getting tiresome. How do I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To type `ऱ्य`

`र` +`़` +`्` + `य`

<kbd>R</kbd> + `Nukta` + `Half` + `Viram` (`Halanta`) + <kbd>Y</kbd> (or next letter)

Typing in Devanagari Inscript

<kbd>J</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I not sure if I am missing some thing obvious..

but its just `r` to insert `र्`. BTW you can ask emacs itself about the input system.. `M-x describe-input-method`

Comment: This is half-R. It is typically used in marathi language commonly followed by 'y'. e.g. ऱ्या . This should be actually mapped to 'R' key, but it seems like this is a bug and it is not. M-x describe-input-method does not list this key at all.